# What does the extldi instruction do? (PowerPc)

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I don't understand the instruction `extldi`. The exact operation I want to work out is:

`r12` = 0xB070

```
extldi    r11, r12, 31,17
```

I've looked through many different documentation sources but can't seem to come across a good enough example in order for me to understand it; Rather than giving me the answer I would like an explanation so that it helps in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking into consideration the fact that `extldi` is an extended mnemonic, how should the explanation look like? Do you want to know how to use `rldicr` as well?

Comment: Yes that would be nice also.

Comment: Alright, I am going to edit my answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extldi` is an extended mnemonic for `rldicr` which is ***Rotate Left Doubleword
Immediate then Clear Right***

`extldi Rx,Ry,n,b` is equivalent to `rldicr Rx,Ry,b,n-1`

Additional information can be found by consulting the *PowerPC Architecture Book, Version 2.02*, available [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-archguide-v2.html)

---

**EDIT** - Further information about `rldicr`:

> Rotate the contents of a general purpose register left by the number
>   of bits specified by an immediate value. Clear a specified number of
>   low-order bits. Place the results in another general purpose register.

`rldicr` has four parameters:

- ***RA*** Specifies the target general purpose register for the result of
  the instruction.
- ***RS*** Specifies the source general purpose register containing the
  operand.
- ***SH*** Specifies the (immediate) shift value for the operation.
- ***ME*** Specifies the end value (bit number) of the mask for the
  operation.

**Caution**: This instruction is defined only for 64-bit implementations. Using it on a 32-bit implementation will cause the system illegal instruction error handler to be invoked.

Regarding your situation, you just plugin the numbers and you're done. I hope this edit will please you.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, you can **mark it as an answer** by clicking on the **check** icon under the vote count. Have a nice day!

Comment: For my understanding I did r12 >> 17 & 0x1FFFFFFFC, I don't seem to think this is correct

Comment: No I'm not saying you are incorrect I'm saying that I'm incorrect the way I'm trying to use the information you have given me. r12 >> 17 & 0x1FFFFFFFC

Comment: No, I apologize for not having enough time to plug in the numbers and see what's wrong with your addresses.